# Calculate bankroll Martingale system

Tags: python

I want to write simple martingale system to count how much money will be there in "my" account after x spins on the roulette. The program is simple and just for experiment. So far I have this but, I want to add that if that random number a is for example two times or more... the same as d I would double my bet. So if.. a = 2 and a = 5 I would bet 4 instead of two and so on 8,16,32..

```
from random import*
money = 100
bet = 2
d = [0, 2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23, 26, 29, 32, 35]
for i in range(100):
    a = randint(1, 36)
    if a in d:
        money -= bet
    else:
        money += bet
print("Your money",money,"€")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a `repeat` variable, and use that to see if you got `a in d` consecutively.

```
from random import randint # Bad practice to import *

money = 100
bet = 2

# Consider revising the below to sets, which are faster for membership tests
d = [0, 2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23, 26, 29, 32, 35]

repeat = False

for _ in range(100):  # You never use the loop variable, so denote that by naming it _
    a = randint(1, 36) # btw, you have 0 in d but your randint starts from 1...

    if a in d:
        money -= bet
        if repeat:
            bet *= 2
        repeat = True
    else:
        money += bet
        repeat = False

print("Your money",money,"€")
```

You didn't specify what happens to the bet value when you lose a bet.  The above simply keeps raising stakes if you win a bet consecutively.  The bet value will not go down when you lose.

If you want to reset the bet value, you would just store that data in a separate variable like `original_bet` and reset with `bet = original_bet` within the `else` clause.